# update with join with latest record from other table without primary key column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables :
1. lastorder

```
id  username    ordername
1   user1       null
2   user2       null
3   user3       null
```

2.orders

```
ordername    username
order1      user1
order2      user1
order3      user2
order4      user3
order5      user2
order6      user3
order7      user3
```

I want to update lastorder table in such a way that the ordername column will have last order placed from orders table.
Final result of lastorder table:

```
 id  username    ordername
1   user1       order2
2   user2       order5
3   user3       order7
```

I do not have an id column in orders table.This is because orders is actually a subquery result not an actual table.But for simplicity let us consider it as table.
If I had id column my query would have been like this:

```
 update lastorder l inner join 
    (select ordername,username from orders where id in 
(select max(id) from orders group by username)) as o
    on u.username = o.username set l.ordername = o.ordername;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a table, create a view. That will "update" itself automatically.

```
DROP TABLE lastorder;

CREATE VIEW lastorder
AS
SELECT a.id,
       a.username,
       o.ordername
       FROM (SELECT username,
                    max(id) id
                    FROM orders
                    GROUP BY username) a
            INNER JOIN orders o
                       ON o.id = a.id;
```

Comment: I cannot use max(ordername) as the ordernames are placed in chronological order.The names can be anything, and not in ascending order as I have mentioned above.Its just example.

Comment: @Frank: Then you can get the maximum id per user name and join the orders to get the order's name. See the edit.

Comment: @Frank: Sorry, I overlooked that there's no `id` in `orders`. So replace `id` with any column, that defines the order (in terms of order of insertion).

Answer (score 0):

You could use subquery for max id  and with this retrive the related  ordername

```
  update lastorder l 
  inner join (
      select  o.ordername, o.username 
      from  orders o 
      inner join  (
        select  max(id)  max_id, username
        fromn orders 
        group by username
      ) t on t.max_id  =  o.id 
  ) t2 on l.username = t2.username 
  selt l.ordername  = t.ordername
```

or assuming your last order is obtained  by max(ordername)

```
  update lastorder l 
  inner join (
        select  max(ordename)  max_order, username
        fromn orders 
        group by username
      ) t2 on l.username = t2.username 
  sel  l.ordername  = t2.max_order
```

Comment: I dont have an Id column in orders.